# Rails: users/index routing to users/show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Whenever I try to access the index method of my user controller, I get an error from rails that says the following:

Unknown action
The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController

My routes.rb file does not have a route to show, but it does have one to index.
Even when I enter localhost:3000/users/index into my url bar, I still get the same issue.

I have been looking for an answer to this question for hours and have still had no luck.

EDIT:

I took the advice to route with get 'users/index' => 'users#index', but that did not help. The index.html.erb is in the right place. I have an index method defined in my users_controller.rb

The section of my routes.rb:

```
get 'users/index' => 'users#index'
get 'users/sign_up_partial'
post 'users/create'
```

Comment: Please post your routes.rb, at least the relevant parts of it

Comment: Realize that the error message is the best advice you have so far. Somewhere, something is linking to "show." Having your index.html.erb file is not so relevant to the error. I agree, post your routes.rb file, we need more data to help you.

Comment: Do you have a users resource defined in routes before this?

Comment: You should post your entire routes.rb file. We cannot see if other routes are defined above your users#index definition. Because the order changes the game on the routes table.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'localhost:3000/users/index'. It will redirect to show. 
If you will do rake route you will find

/users/:id(.:format) will redirect to show action of users controller and in your case as you are using users/index its considering 'index' as user id.

For index action you just need to use URL 'localhost:3000/users'.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you should have in your routes.rb file:

```
get "users/index" => "users#index"
```

Have your index defined in your users_controller.rb

and

make sure you have the view file created (views/users/index.html.erb)